# Encoding issues with R and Tibco

Tags: r, postgresql, tibco

We have around 4 R scripts embedded in a master R script (which calls all the scripts). 
If we run this R script from the command prompt using all the args required for that job, its running fine and giving the proper encoding. But If we run it from the tibco scheduler in the same environment, its not properly giving the encoding.I am writing output to CSV files.
Input is Postgres db. 
I am using data.table option and dbgetquery to connect to Databse.

Following are two different resukts I am getting for a particular column :-

From backend command prompt - PIZZÃƒâ€ž
From Front end tibco - PIZZ<84>

I would request you to kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: Have you specified the `encoding` argument in `source()`?

Comment: No actually, do you want me to try it with latin1 encoding

Comment: If that's how your files are encoded, it's worth a try

Comment: please give me some time,  I will try and let you know

Comment: No luck sir, It't not working even after trying thar source encoding option